# Can not import 'Logger' from 'utils' error

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

Can't import Logger module from utils, Here is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from utils import Logger
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Salvatore/Desktop/Python/Preme", line 4, in <module>
    from utils import Logger
ImportError: cannot import name 'Logger' from 'utils' (C:\Users\Salvatore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

[image: These are a list of my imports, and showing that Logger would not import.]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `logging.Logger`? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html?highlight=utils%20logger#logging.Logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utils doesn't have a module named logger. Use python_utils instead

Run `pip uninstall utils`

Then `pip install python_utils`

Finally

```
# Example 1

from python_utils.logger import Logged

class MyClass(Logged):
    def __init__(self):
        Logged.__init__(self)


my_class = MyClass()
my_class.error('error')
```

Here is more info on the python_utils package, [python_utils](https://python-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_utils.html#)

Depending on your need, it might also be easier to simply use Python's built in logging capabilities with:

```
# Example 2

import logging

logging.error('error')
```

Here is a link to the learn more about logging, [python builtin logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: If your just looking for a simple way to log events then Python’s logging module is your best bet.

Comment: I ran this code:

```import logging

class MyClass(logging):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.__init__(self)


my_class = MyClass()
my_class.error('error')```

and I got this error:


```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Salvatore/Desktop/Python/py2.py", line 3, in <module>
    class MyClass(logging):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)```

Comment: I gave you two different examples based on what you are trying to achieve. If you are writing your code using Classes and you want those classes to have logging capabilities then you can use `from python_utils.logger import Logged` otherwise just use `import logging` and then call `logging.error('error you want to log')` whenever you have something to log.

Comment: ```from python_utils.logger import Logged

class MyClass(Logged):
    def __init__(self):
        Logged.__init__(self)


my_class = MyClass()
my_class.error('error')
```

Returned an error of:
```  from python_utils.logger import Logged
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_utils'```


Even tho I installed python_utils using pip as u told me

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213720/discussion-between-kickin-wing-and-salvatore-timpani).